# Facebook Country list for user locations

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Is there a list of "facebook country names"? 
in my iphone app , after retrieving the location information, I want to select the country back, and the user will be able to change it, so I have to find the list of countries and, if possible cities, used by facebook

Answer (score 0):

I believe Facebook uses the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes (2 digit country codes, ie United Kingdom is 'GB').

http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm